# Как в Zend Framework 3 организовать несколько зависимых проектов?

Tags: zend-framework

Начну с аналогии. Есть такой **фреймворк Yii2** и при его установки через **composer** в варианте **advanced** сразу разворачивается вся необходимая структура каталогов.

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced yii-application
```

- Каталог **frontend** - публичная часть сайт (***frontend/public*** - в него смотрит домен ***mysite.domain***).
- Каталог **backend** - сюда сразу можно вешать например админку (каталог
  ***backend/public*** - в него смотрит домен ***admin.mysite.domain***).
- Остальные каталоги - это уже движок и т.п.

Каталоги ***backend*** и ***frontend*** содержат внутри себя свои контроллеры, модели и представления...

Если нужно добавить еще один скажем так "подпроект", например - блог, то мы просто создаем директорию ***blog*** на том же уровне, где лежат ***backend*** и ***frontend***, заводим в новой директории нужную внутреннюю структуру каталогов (для представлений, контроллеров, моделей), ассоциируем домен ***blog.mysite.domain*** с директорией ***blog/public*** и немного корректируем конфиги фреймворка и роутинг - всё.

Теперь сам вопрос.

**Как организовывается такая распределенная структура каталогов в фреймворке Zend Framework 3?**

Проект один, но некоторые его части (например, админка, блог и еще что-нибудь) должны быть вынесены на поддомены. Хочется правильно понять как организовать роутинг между подпроектами и как разделять MVC проектов.  Документацию разумеется читаю. Но пока не могу свести всё воедино. Буду рад подсказкам и ссылкам на информацию по данному вопросу.

Comment: А зачем всё в одну кучу "кидать"? Разделайте всё

Comment: Так это и есть разделение. Фреймворк 1 для всего проект с подпроектами. Если например нам надо в подпроекте Админки использовать какую-нибудь публичную модель - обращаемся к ней по полному неймсейсу и все. И вопрос мой всё же о другом... Не "зачем", а "как".

Comment: Если как, то наверное в apache прописываете свой домен, указываете ему на папку допустим на blog/public, и далее в этой index.php добавляете в include пути к папкам с модулями и т.д. Наверное так